# Can't merge a non object mapping [suggest] with an object mapping [suggest]

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-data-elasticsearch, search-suggestion

I'm using Spring with Elastic Search. I have entity with `Completion` field, which is being used for suggest:

```
@Document(indexName = "entity_index", type = "entity")
public class Entity {
@Id
private Long id;

....

@CompletionField(maxInputLength = 30,payloads = true)
private Completion suggest;
...
```

}

When I start my Spring Boot app - all is good, no errors.
But when I want to start my elastic search unit tests, I get error:

```
Failed to load Application Context

....

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't merge a non object mapping [suggest] with an object mapping [suggest]
```

So, please help me solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue via deleting `data` folder that contains elasticsearch data.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change existing mappings.

if you can loss data - delete index and re-create it with new mappings.
if you need to keep your data - create new index with new mappings and copy data from old index to new one - them date old one and create alias with old name to point new new index

In your case i suspect that you have created index with field not mark as @CompletionField and added the annotation later and that why you see that error.